# Angular - access dynamically created form elements from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple form, generated with ng-repeat:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <button ng-click="addFormElement()">+</button>

    <div ng-repeat="model in models">
        <input type="text" name="formElement{{$index}}" ng-model="model.value" />
    </div>
</form>
```

New elements are added by clicking the "plus" button. Here is the code:

```
$scope.addFormElement = function() {
    $scope.models.push({ value: "test"});

    console.log($scope.myForm);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.models.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.myForm["formElement"+i]);
    }
};
```

The problem: in the first console log I can see the currently added new input field, but when I try to print the concrete element in the for cycle it logs "undefined". When I add more elements, the last one (currently added) is always defined in first log, but undefined in second. Do you have any idea why?

[Printscreen of logs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU56B.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a plnkr where you will find a solution:

```
$timeout(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.models.length; i++) {
    console.log($scope.myForm["formElement"+i]);
  } 
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/oTttVJrAOiSRn3jfde5q

You should call it within a **$timeout**. You need it for waiting to the **next digest cycle** of angular. Internally $timeout will call $apply and it will force to synchronize the two way data binding.